# Sum all numbers in a given range of a given list Python

Tags: python, sum, range, indices

How can I write a function to get the sum of the items in the given list between the indices a and b. For example give `aList=[6,3,4,2,5]` and `a=1`, `b=3`, the function should return 9. Here is my code:

```
def sumRange(L,a,b):
    sum= []
    L = [6,3,4,2,5]
    for i in range(a,b+1,1):
    sum +=L[i]
    return sum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want do roll your own solution. You can do it like this (based on the code you had in your question):

```
def sumRange(L,a,b):                                                                                                                                                                                                
    sum = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    for i in range(a,b+1,1):                                                                                                                                                                                        
        sum += L[i]                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    return sum                                                                                                                                                                                                      

L = [6,3,4,2,5]                                                                                                                                                                                                     
a = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                               
b = 3                                                                                                                                                                                                               

result = sumRange(L,a,b)                                                                                                                                                                                            

print "The result is", result
```

This program prints

> The result is 9

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve this with list slicing:

```
sum(your_list[a:b + 1])
```

Here, `your_list[a:b+1]` is a *slice* - a part of *your list* starting from the index `a` and ending with the index `b`, *including the values at both indexes* (this is why you need `b + 1`).

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use index slicing in python and the sum function.

```
return sum(L[a:b])
```